# Does using string_view lead to an unnecessary string copy in this scenario?

Tags: c++, string-view

What I'm trying to do is have my class accept a string during construction. I read that `string_view` was a replacement for `const string&` so naturally I wrote a constructor like this. This allows me to accept c++ and c strings.

```
Url::Url(boost::string_view raw_url)
    : url_(static_cast<std::string>(raw_url)) {
```

The problem which might be here is that when an rvalue is passed, there is a unnecessary copy instead of a move. Is the solution to make another constructor which takes `string&&`? What is the best practice here?

Comment: Constructors that supposed to _move in_ some data usually accept just value, not rvalue reference. That is simpler.

Comment: Make a constructor that takes the parameter by value and moves it into `url_`.

Comment: The point is to move into the member `url_(std::move(raw_url))`, Then you will only get one copy. You will get one extra move for lvalues, but you only need to write one constructor that deals with all cases. Depends how important that extra move is for performance compared to more boiler plate code I guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note: I'll write the answer considering `std::string_view`, but `boost::string_view` should be similar.

---

> I read that string_view was a replacement for const string&

It is useful to understand the reason why `std::string_view` was added in the first place.

**What is the problem with `const string&`?**

It is certainly efficient if you pass an `std::string` object and you don't gain anything with `std::string_view`. But suppose now that you are passing a `char*` containing a large string. In that case a temporary `std::string` object will be created (and the whole string referenced by that `char*` will be copied) just so the function receives an `std::string`. That is when `std::string_view` shines. If you pass a `char*` or a `std::string` (or anything that can be converted to `std::string_view`) to a function accepting `std::string_view` (by value, no need to accept a `std::string_view` by reference) then the new `std::string_view` object that is created is very cheap, since it is only "a view" and it does not copy the underlying string.

---

But your case is different. Since **you are copying the string** anyway, then your function should just accept a string **by value** and move the string inside the function. Something such as

```cpp
Url::Url(std::string raw_url)
    : url_(std::move(raw_url)) {
```

There is even a [clang-tidy warning](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/modernize-pass-by-value.html) to tell you this.

The advantage is that if the user of your function pass an lvalue you make a copy (you need it anyway) and a move, but if they pass an rvalue then there is no copy and only a move.

Comment: This is not an equivalent code - such function does not accept `string_view` as an argument.

Comment: You are right. It does not accept a `string_view`. However, it seemed the only reason the OP was trying to use `string_view` instead of a string was due to efficiency concerns and in his particular case a regular string passed by value seems like a better option.

Comment: It would be possible to add a constructor taking `string_view` as well, if that is actually desired

Comment: @M.M It won't work because `const char*` conversion becomes ambiguous. And this is why I don't like what clang-tidy suggests in this case - the only "valid" way is to provide 3 overloads: `const char *`, `std::string_view` and `std::string&&`.